News Post in SharePoint Online, Can We Change The From Email Address To A Separate Email Using Microsoft Power Automate?
We are using a SharePoint Online site. It's a Communication Site. In that SharePoint site we use the 'News post' web part.
Once created a News post, we share it as 'Sens as email'.
We want to change the 'From' email address as opposed to the post author's email address.
Ideally how we can send the news post with a different email address as the 'From email address' using Microsoft Power Automate.
We tried the below options but at each of these, we had to build the email template from the scratch.

Outlook Send an email action.
List item Mail action.
Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action.

Please can someone help me on this?
Regards,
Chiranthaka

Can someone please look into this request?
